# How to use css property under a class only

Tags: css

I have a css property like this

```
:before,
:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

it is affecting the whole page . So i need it affect all type of element only under 'togglebox' class . So how my syntax should be .

Comment: `.togglebox:before, .togglebox:after` - Please read up on this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: What do you mean by "under" the togglebox class? Should it affect elements that are descendants of elements that have the togglebox class, or should it affect only the elements that have the togglebox class?

Comment: I have answered based on what you actually asked. I have also added an update to answer the question in your comment. Please re-word your question to be more specific if this is still not what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the class you want to apply your CSS rules to, like so:

```
.myclass:before,
.myclass:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You would then need `class="myclass"` within the elements you want this style to apply to, in your case this would be your "togglebox". I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "togglebox", but I assume it would read as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="togglebox" class="myclass"/>
```

UPDATE: Given the comment below, it looks like you want to apply the style to the *children* of your "togglebox" - this is a pretty easy modification:

```
.myclass *:before,
.myclass *:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This css rule will now apply to any (hence the `*`) element that is a *descendent* (immediate children or their children and so forth).

If you want to apply the rule only to *direct children* (and not children of children and so forth) you would use:

```
.myclass > *:before,
.myclass > *:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information.

Comment: It can't be an `input` as they don't have pseudo elements. Also, I'd suggest updating your answer to use double colons, per the CSS3 spec.

Comment: I know this rule but I need to apply this css property to all type of element under .toggle class
So it is not solving my problem . Waiting for the answer .

Comment: Updated - does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
.togglebox:before,
.togglebox:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```